# C# How to nextline in e.Drawing when printing images

Tags: c#

I'm generating a barcode depending on how many inputs that the user set in the `numericUpDown` control. The problem is when generating a lot of barcodes, the other barcodes cannot be seen in the `printpreviewdialog` because it I cannot apply a nextline or `\n` every 4-5 Images.

```
int x = 0, y = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= int.Parse(txtCount.Text); i++)
{
     idcount++;
     connection.Close();
     Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
     Random random = new Random();
     string randomtext = "MLQ-";
     int j;
     for (j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
     {
          randomtext += random.Next(0, 9).ToString();

          Image barcodeimg = barcode.Draw(randomtext, 50);

          resultimage = new Bitmap(barcodeimg.Width, barcodeimg.Height + 20);
          using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resultimage))
          using (var font = new Font("Arial", 11)) // Any font you want
          using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
          using (var format = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far}) // Also, horizontally centered text, as in your example of the expected output
          {
                graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                graphics.DrawImage(barcodeimg, 0, 0);
                graphics.DrawString(randomtext, font, brush, resultimage.Width / 2, resultimage.Height, format);
          }

          x += 25;

     }
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(resultimage, x, y);
}
```

[image]

Comment: "nextline" does not make sense, you are going to have to increase the `y` variable.  Once you got that done you are going to have to do something about having too many barcodes to fit a page, e.HasMorePages property.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "new lines" in rasterized graphics. There's pixels. You've got the right idea, every `n` number of images, add a new line. But since you're working with pixels, let's say every 4 images you're going to need to add a vertical offset by modifying the y coordinate of all your graphics draw calls. This offset, combined with a row height in pixels could look something like this:

```
var rowHeight = 250;  // pixels
var maxColumns = 4;
var verticalOffset = (i % maxColums) * rowHeight;
```

Then, when you can supply a y coordinate, starting at or near 0, add the vertical offset to it.